# Limpiar variable $_POST despues de enviar un formulario

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Tengo un problema con un formulario que es validado con Jquery, el problema es que mi formulario se envía correcto y se valida bien, cuando termina la validación me envía a mi pagina de inicio, el problema es que cuando estoy en la pagina de inicio si recargo con F5 me muestra el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porque pasa esto, esta es la ventana que me muestra cuando presiono F5 o actualizo la pagina:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El formulario lo proceso con Jquery de la siguiente forma:

```
$("#form-solicitud").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            
            let myForm = document.getElementById('form-solicitud');
            let formData = new FormData(myForm);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/proyecto/panel/controlador/ctr_solicitud.php",
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
        
                    var mensajesErrores;

                    try {
                        mensajesErrores = JSON.parse(data);
                    } catch (error) {
                        mensajesErrores = '';
                    }

                    if(mensajesErrores == '' || mensajesErrores == null){

                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'success',
                            title: 'Tu solicitud se registró con éxito',
                            html: 'Recibirás un <b>correo electrónico</b> con el resumen de tu solicitud.',
                            showConfirmButton: true,
                            confirmButtonText: '¡Genial!'
                        }).then((result) =>{
                            if (result.isConfirmed) {                                
                                form.submit();
                                //unset($_POST);
                            }else{                                
                                form.submit();
                                //unset($_POST);
                            }
                        })

                    }else{

                        // Lista de texto
                        var mensaje = '<ul class="lista-errores" >';
                        mensajesErrores.forEach(element => {
                            mensaje += '<li>'+element+'</li>';
                        });
                        mensaje += '</ul>';

                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'error',
                            title: 'Error al registrar tu solicitud.',
                            text: 'Tu solicitud tiene los siguientes errores: ',
                            html: mensaje,
                            width: '50%',
                            confirmButtonColor: "#AA0000",   
                            confirmButtonText: "¡Entendido!",
                            footer: '<a class="link-error" href="mailto:top@dominio.org.mx?Subject=Sistema%20de%20contratos">Si tienes dudas, envíanos un correo.</a>'
                        })

                    }            
                
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Para el direccionamiento de mi pagina uso un archivo .htaccess

Comment: Asegúrate que no esté haciendo un refresh sobre la misma página que hiciste el post. Si haces rewrite rule y este sobre la misma pasara lo mismo. Imtenta redirigir hacia una URL diferente.

Comment: Si, creo que es lo de rewrite rule, intentare cambiar la url, pero mi idea era enviarlo al inicio, el problema es que sobre esa url se hace el refresh

Comment: Si no son daros sensibles podrían ir por get y eso no pasa.

Comment: Y no puedo limpiar la variable $_POST ? me refiero a que cuando me envié al inicio limpio la variable $_POST? pregunto porque intente con unset($_POST) y con algo asi $_POST = array(); y no ha servidor

Comment: Encontré algunas soluciones en inglés. No es exactamente pero creo que te puede ayudar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570015/how-do-i-reload-a-page-without-a-postdata-warning-in-javascript

Comment: prueba con  `$_POST = [];` al final de tu  codigo

Comment: Me parece que lo que ocurre aquí es que tienes mal organizado el código. Me pregunto, ¿por qué motivo hay que darle a F5 si usas Ajax cuando puedes: A. Redirigir a otra página una vez la petición Ajax completada o B. Actualizar el contenedor de la página in situ, sin necesidad de cambiar de página? No veo el sentido que tenga F5 aquí.

Comment: @A.Cedano amm no es que debas usar el F5, el formulario se valida y se envía con Ajax, una vez que el formulario se valido se envía y se guarda en la BD y después direcciona al usuario al inicio, el problema surgió por que me di cuenta que si ya una vez que estabas en el inicio apretabas F5 me daba ese error.

Comment: @WilfredoAleman Eso funciono, el problema era que después de que el formulario era procesado en AJAX, a la pagina donde redireccionaba después de que era procesado el formulario me seguía llegando la información en a variable $_POST